# HTML text field not displaying decimal places of SQL money value

Tags: sql, html, asp-classic

I have a text field who's value is populated from a SQL recordset (below).

```
<input name="txtAmount" id="txtAmount" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" value="<%=RS("Amount")%>">
```

In the SQL table, the Amount field (which is a money data type) is inserted correctly, as `5.00`  However, in the web page, it displays only as `5` (i.e. the decimal places are missing).  Anyone know why this might be and how I can get the decimal places to display in the field?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the dollar sign, use

```
value="<%=FormatNumber(RS("Amount"),2)%>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Applying formating will do the trick:

```
<input name="txtAmount" id="txtAmount" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" 
       value="<%=FormatCurrency(RS("Amount"), 2)%>">
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is in .NET, you can use

```
<%= String.Format("{0:0.00}", RS("Amount")) %>
```

Comment: i'm actually using classic ASP.  is there an equivalent to String.Format for that?